# Why does `SameQ` act inconsistently with `Image`s wrapped in `{}` versus not?

Tags: image, expression-test, language-design

Take an `Image` that is displayed in a `GraphicsBox`, e.g. the result of `Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"]`, and place a copy of it next to it, separated by `===`.

Evaluating this will give `True`. If you resize one of the images, you still get `True`.

This makes some sense conceptually, because data-wise, the images are the same. The underlying expression however changed (look at the FullForm or BoxForm of the two) and I thought `SameQ` is supposed to test structural expression equivalence.

Irritatingly, this seems to be what is reported once you put these expressions into braces:

`{-put the first image here-} === {-put it's resized copy here-}`

gives `False`. Only if you put an exact copy of either one of them you get `True` again.

`Equal` is much more consistent: It gives `True` in all of the above cases.

One has to be aware of this if one develops tests in Testing Notebooks: The default `SameTest` is `SameQ`, which works because of the above with single-`Image` output but can start to fail once you put images together with other results into lists.

Answer (score 5):

I strongly suspect that this is special overloading of `SameQ` for `Image` objects, and that this overloading was only made for elements at level one, possibly via internal [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html).  Here is a mockup using neither `SameQ` nor `Equal`:

```
mySameQ[a___, i_Image, b___] := mySameQ[a, ImageData @ i, b]

mySameQ[a_, a_, x___] := mySameQ[a, x]
mySameQ[_] := True
mySameQ[else__] := False
```

This replicates the behavior of `SameQ` in the cases you describe.

Comment: +1 - I'd venture the fact an image is an atom, and that is lost when enclosed in braces, is the trigger...

Comment: @ciao That *almost* seems like a restatement of what I wrote, or at least intended.  Are you agreeing with me, or suggesting that a method different from what I described and demonstrated is the cause?

Comment: I am absolutely agreeing. Have I ever *not* agreed with you? ;=}